# How to loop my whole program?

Tags: java, loops

```
import java.util.*;
public class Lab4
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Body Fat Calculator");

        double A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,B; //female
        double a1,a2,b; //male
        double bodyWeight,wristMeasurement,waistMeasurement,hipMeasurement,forearmMeasurement; //both
        double bodyFat,bodyFatpercent; //both

        Scanner body = new Scanner (System.in);


        System.out.println ("Enter Gender (m/f): ");
        char gender = body.nextLine().charAt(0);


        while ((gender != 'm') && (gender != 'f')) {
            System.out.println ("Unknown gender, Enter gender again (m/f); ");
            gender = body.nextLine ().charAt(0);


        }


        do
        {
         if (gender == 'm') {
                System.out.println ("Enter Your Body Weight: ");
                bodyWeight = body.nextInt ();

                System.out.println ("Enter Your Waist Measurement: ");
                waistMeasurement = body.nextDouble ();

                a1 = (bodyWeight * 1.082) + 94.42; //male formula
                a2 = waistMeasurement * 4.15;
                b = a1 - a2;

                bodyFat = bodyWeight - b;
                bodyFatpercent = bodyFat * 100 / bodyWeight;

                System.out.printf ("%s %.2f%%%n", "Your Bodyfat Percentage is: ", bodyFatpercent);
            }

                else {

                System.out.println ("Enter Your Body Weight: ");
                bodyWeight = body.nextInt ();

                System.out.println ("Enter Your Wrist Measurement: ");
                wristMeasurement = body.nextDouble ();

                System.out.println ("Enter Your Waist Measurement: ");
                waistMeasurement = body.nextDouble ();

                System.out.println ("Enter Your Hip Measurement: ");
                hipMeasurement = body.nextDouble ();

                System.out.println ("Forearm Your Measurement: ");
                forearmMeasurement = body.nextDouble ();

                A1 = (bodyWeight * 0.732) + 8.987; // female formula
                A2 = wristMeasurement / 3.14; //at fullest point
                A3 = waistMeasurement * 0.157; //at navel
                A4 = hipMeasurement * 0.249; //at fullest point
                A5 = forearmMeasurement * 0.434; //at fullest point
                B = A1 + A2 - A3 - A4 + A5;

                bodyFat = bodyWeight - B;
                bodyFatpercent = bodyFat * 100 / bodyWeight;
                System.out.printf ("%s %.2f%%%n", "Your Bodyfat Percentage is: ", bodyFatpercent);
            }
        }
        while ((gender == 'm') && (gender != 'm'));
            System.out.println ("Would You Like to Use the Calculator Again (y/n)? ");


        }      
    }
```

How do I loop my whole program so that the user can use it again and again?

Comment: your code makes absolutely no sense at the end. you say `while((gender == 'm') && (gender != 'm'))` and those two conditions contradict each other. They will never both be true and therefore what is in the loop will never be called

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do i loop my whole program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21978065/how-do-i-loop-my-whole-program)

Answer (score 4):

There are a few ways to do it, the generally preffered way would probably be to surround the entire main function with a `while(true){` `}`, and maybe at the end you prompt the user askng if he/she wants to do it again and if he/she says no you call `break`.